# Returning a SUBSET of a multidimensional array that satisfies a particular condition?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

Basically taking a multidimensional array and checking to see whether the 3rd column of the array is the hypotenuse of the first and second columns. This is the code I have so far. I've added some stuff in the comments to sort of facilitate a better understanding of what's going on.

```
import numpy
import random

def triple(mm):
    mm=np.asanyarray(mm) # I think this is how we specify that the paremeter should be an array, however,
    # it's possible the parameter isn't just mm, it could be 'j', 'qw', 'mm1', whatever. I'm not sure
    # how to work that while specifying the parameter must be array.
assert mm.ndim == 2 # we want mm or w/e the name of the parameter to be a 1 multidimensional array
assert mm.shape[1] == 3 # we want 3 columns, with any number of rows 
    x = mm[:,0]
    y = mm[:,1]
    z = mm[:,2] # 3rd column is to be checked to see if its's the hypotenuse of 1st & 2nd columns   
    zz = np.hypot(x,y)
    condition = np.any(z) == np.any(zz)
    return np.array([condition, mm]) # I'm not sure how to specify it here, that we want the function to return a subset
        # of the original multi-dim array, where the 3rd column is in fact the hypotenuse of the first and 
        # second columns. And we want to exclude the rows that don't satisfy this condition.
```

And I'd want to check   :

```
mm = np.array([[5,5,5],[5,12,13],[3,4,5],[5,11,21],[8,15,17]])
triple(mm)
```

But the error I'm getting is :

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I'm not sure if that 'condition' I set is even the right way to go about this, so can someone help steer me in the right direction?
Feel free to ask for more clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

A vectored way to do that is :

This compute `x²+y²-z²` on each line `(axis=1)`

```
In [1]: goods=(mm*mm*[1,1,-1]).sum(axis=1)==0


In [2]: goods
Out[2]: array([False,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

And with [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) :

```
In [3]: mm[goods]
Out[3]: 
array([[ 5, 12, 13],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 8, 15, 17]])
```

Your condition is not good : `np.any(z) == np.any(zz)` is true if `zz` and `z` are not the null vector.

`np.array([condition, mm])` is here `np.array ([ True, [[5....]] ])` , which trig the error message.

Comment: But what I want is an output that returns the rows where the condition is satisfied (basically return all the Pythagorean triples). So it should be: 
`array([[5,12,13], [ 3,4,5], [8,15,17]])`

Comment: Edited. use boolean indexing.

Comment: Okay, it works but I'm not really understanding how `goods` is operating? Like the logic of it ...

Comment: What does the axis do?

Comment: and what's `mm*mm*[1,1,-1])` ? Why do you multiply(?)